# How to deploy a Postgres container with multi CN certificates

Tags: postgresql, docker, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I Have the following scenario:

A Postgres docker container deployed with verify full ssl on a cloud VM.

In the same Host via docker network, I have an API that connects to that database (This api will call the postgres host: "postgres" because that's how is defined in the docker network).

I also have the demand to open that postgres database to external connection (via the server's IP).

However, the Self Signed Certificate used the CN='postgres', making external connections fail because the "hostname" isnt "postgres" but the IP for that VM.

How to approach this scenario? Is it possible to have more than one CA for the same postgres instance?

EDIT: Here's how I generated the Certificates:

CA (root): `openssl req  -nodes -new -x509  -keyout server.key -out server.crt -subj '/C=BR/ST=SP/L=SP/O=postgres/CN=postgres`

Ext file content: `echo "subjectAltName=DNS:postgres,IP:10.40.2.5" >> extfile.cnf`

Client cert:

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out client/postgresql.key 2048

openssl rsa -in client/postgresql.key -out client/postgresql.key

openssl req -new -key client/postgresql.key -out client/postgresql.csr -subj '/C=BR/ST=SP/L=SP/O=postgres/CN=postgres'

openssl x509 -req -in client/postgresql.csr -CA root.crt -CAkey server.key -out client/postgresql.crt -extfile extfile.cnf -CAcreateserial
```

PGA conf line : hostssl all all all cert clientcert=verify-full

Comment: Hostnames don't get put in the CN, that was deprecated 20 years ago. Instead, they get put in the Subject Alternative Names extension. You can put as many different hostnames there as you want. See RFC 5280 for more details.

Comment: 've made the extension while generating the client certs with the alternate names but the connection to the database always get negated by the client because of the mismatch between the server root CA being cn=postgres and not the IP. @PresidentJamesK.Polk Ive updated the question with the cert generation commands.

Comment: @RenanFernandes: `openssl req -new ... -extfile extfile.cnf` - openssl req does not have an option -extfile and you should get an error when trying to do this. Also, since the client complains about the server certificate not having the right name you should fix the server certificate - i.e. add the subject alternative names with the IP address to the server certificate and not the client certificate.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich So I should add it to the first certificate I create right? what would  be the syntax for it using the single command line? (edited the -req with the ext file option. I indeed got an error but forgot to remove it from my copy pasta script file xD).

Comment: if you're using lipq, you can use use a combination of `hostaddr` and `host` to solve this issue. Put the server's IP in `hostaddr` and the CN in `host`, e.g. `"hostaddr=10.40.2.5 host=postgres"`

Comment: You show us using a root.crt, but never show the creation of it.  You also show us the creation of server.crt, but without showing the signing of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You added the SAN to the client cert, which doesn't make sense.  It is the server, not the client, which needs to have the SAN.

You also seem to be using the same cert as both the server cert and the CA cert (although your given list of commands is inaccurate/incomplete, so I can't be sure).  This is a half-assed way of doing things.  I don't know if it is even possible to add a SAN to a CA.  You should make a CA, and then use it to sign both the server cert and the client cert.  In this way, you will have no difficulty adding the SAN to the server cert and using it (which I just verified, but I had to give the different certs different CN, you use an identical CN for two certs).

Comment: Seems like I followed a bad tutorial on how to make certs for postgres, I will make more research in the topic. Thanks for the clarification.